# HTL Language, string concatenation and ternary operator

Tags: adobe, aem, ternary-operator, string-concatenation, htl

I am using adobe AEM, and the HTL language. I am writing something like:

```
${properties.hash ? [model1.href,properties.hash] @ join='#' : model1.href}
```

But doesn't works. I think it is a syntax problem.. But I am not able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@` token in ternary expression is not a valid token at this place. You can move the `@join` to end of expression.

```
 ${properties.hash ? [model1.href,properties.hash] : model1.href @ join='#'}
```

`@join` doesn't impacts simple string, leaves as it is, which would the case if `properties.hash` is `false`

Comment: Is there any way to do this while also having `@context='styleString'` set? 
ex something like this: `${properties.iconCircle ? ['background-color:', properties.iconCircleColor] : ''  @ join="" @context='styleString'};`